# displaying rate information from stream of numbers

Tags: bash

Are there any command line tools that would make it easy to display rate information based on a stream of newline separated numbers? For example average "count" per second/minute and total "count" so far.

Here's an example source of input:

**counts.py**

```
import random
import time


while True:
    print random.randint(1, 100)
    time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that abuses `pv`:

```
counts.py | xargs -n 1 -I count head -c count /dev/zero | pv -ab > /dev/null
```